# Doubly Linked List Class constructor segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm implementing DLL Class. But I can't figure out why calling my constructor always fail.

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(int value, Node *next, Node *prev);
    ~Node();
    int value;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
Node::Node() {
    this->value = 0;
    this->next = NULL;
    this->prev = NULL;
}
Node::Node(int value, Node *next, Node *prev) {
    this->value = value;
    this->next = next;
    this->prev = prev;
}

class DLLStructure {
public:
    DLLStructure();
    DLLStructure(int *arr, int size);
    
    ~DLLStructure();
    
private:
    Node *first;
    Node *last;
};
DLLStructure::DLLStructure(int arr[], int size) {
    Node *first = NULL;
    Node *last;
    Node *prev;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        //initialize the current node
        last = new Node(arr[i], NULL, NULL);
        if (!first) {
            first = last;
            prev = last;
            continue;
        }

        prev->next = last;
        last->prev = prev;
        prev = last;

    }

    this->first = first;
    this->last = last;
}

int main(){
  int arr[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};
  DLLStructure dll(arr, 5);
  return 0;
}
```

The weird thing is when I comment out `first = last` in the **if block** in **DLL Constructor**, the program returns zero but when I try to print the value of the list, it's again segmentation fault.

Comment: You haven't implemented `~DLLStructure()` so I'm surprised this links.

Comment: Think about `Node *first = NULL;` and `Node *last;` Are you absolutely certain you want to declare new variables here?

Comment: I didn't post destructor. Sorry. I'm new to c++. My idea is that the ```first``` represents the head of the list and ```last``` represents the current node being created.

Comment: You should have just an `Add` function that adds an item to the back of the list.  Then it's just a matter of calling `Add` in a loop.  Currently, your DLLStructure class cannot add nodes after construction.

Comment: Sorry, it's a course assignment and the function signature is unchanged.

Comment: @JacobWong What stops you from creating an Add() function, and in the constructor, simply calling `Add` in a loop?   There is no need to change the constructor's signature to do that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes.. you're right. I should do that. But why my code doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not seeing whatever you are tripping over. `first = last` is absolutely essential. Don't comment it out. If this is making the bug "go away", it's because the list is made without a head pointer and cannot be iterated. I suspect some of the stuff you left out of the question is the actual location of the bug.

Comment: @JacobWong If you refactored your code to simply call `Add` in a loop, don't be surprised if you find the bug yourself and the code magically starts to work.  That also allows a function to have a single responsibility -- add a node to the back.  That makes this issue and any other issues easier to debug and maintain.  Second, the comment section is for comments, not answers -- thus I commented on your current code, and give ideas on how to find the bug *and* create a better implementation of your class.

Comment: Recommendation. Divide and conquer to Isolate the bug. Use [mre] as inspiration. Use the debugger that came with your development tools to step through the program. Watch what happens as it happens with the debugger to help you make sense of the program. When you see the program doing something unexpected, that'll probably be the bug.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you! I fixed it. The bug is in my destructor. I mistakenly pointed to null and call that pointer's prev field.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your comment. While I fixed the bug, I will do what you said.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in my destructor. I mistakenly make  `Node *cur`pointing to null and call `cur->prev`.

Comment: Jacob, In order to make an answer good a future reader must be able to make the connection between the question and the answer. Since there is no destructor in the question, there's no way for anyone but you to make this connection. To fix this problem you will need to add the destructor to the question.